# Color gcc output on mac 10.6.8?

Tags: gcc, text-coloring

I've heard of colorgcc for coloring gcc outputs on the command line, but I can't find documentation on how to get this working on a mac (if it even does?). I'm not really willing to switch to an IDE, so If there are any alternatives for gcc coloring output that would be awesome.

Thanks

Comment: It's perl script. You can find the doc here: http://schlueters.de/colorgcc.html. Just copy and paste the script from here and use that script instead of gcc to compile. Simple :)

Comment: Ok cool! Sorry, I'm still really newbish with bash/terminal/etc. but where do I copy and paste the perl script?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way I can invoke the script whenever I compile with gcc? As of right now I'm using the cpp file as an argument for the script then compiling it with gcc.

Comment: You can create a symlink or an alias. An alias would be: `alias gcc=/path/to/script/colorgcc.pl`  And add that alias in your ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc so that you don't need to run it everytime you open a terminal.

Comment: @KingsIndian: setting the $CC environment variable to the path to colorgcc script in the ~/.profile might be even better